# Brew stopped working after upgrade (High Sierra)

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

After upgrading brew, I can't install anymore casks. It gives me a error about xattr:

```
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemAlternateNames \(\"chromium\"\) /usr/local/Caskroom/chromium/869663/chromium.wrapper.sh` exited with 1. Here's the output:
  File "/usr/bin/xattr", line 31
    continue
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was version of my python and xattr which uses python@3 instead of python@2.

this will fix the issue for now:

`sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/xattr-2.7 $(which xattr)`